# Selection o the value that corresponds to the intersection between columns and rows

Tags: python, select

```
PRODUCT VALUE         NUMBER OF PAYMENTS
```

---

| MIN VALUE | MAX VALUE | 1 TO 6 | 7 TO 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 1000 | 2% | 4% |
| 1001 | ∞ | 3% | 5% |

This is a small sample of the table of % interest to pay (the actual table is 5x5), I need to select the interest between a value and a number of payment installments, eventually I did with conditional---- **were 81 lines of code**, well for me it was ok, but  I kept thinking what would be the "professional solution" using tables, pandas or numpy.

For example if my product cost 1500 USD, With 2 payments my interest rate would be 3%

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas the first part is easy. Replace `MAX VALUE` (where it is `∞`) with a large integer (e.g. 1000000) and then you can select the appropriate row using:

```py
product_value = 1500
df[(df['MIN VALUE'] <= product_value) & (df['MAX VALUE'] >= product_value)]
#    MIN VALUE  MAX VALUE 1 TO 6 7 TO 11
# 1       1001    1000000    3%       5%
```

The hard part is selecting the appropriate column from that row. One way to do that would be to create ranges from the column names:

```py
ranges = { k : range(int(v[0]),int(v[1])+1) for k, v in [ (c, c.split(' TO ')) for c in df.columns ] if len(v) == 2}
print(ranges)
# {'1 TO 6': range(1, 7), '7 TO 11': range(7, 12)}
```

Then you could select the column from that dictionary:

```py
no_payments = 2
col = [k for k, v in ranges.items() if no_payments in v][0]
# '1 TO 6'
```

Finally you can find the value you want using the row and column indexes:

```py
df[(df['MIN VALUE'] <= product_value) & (df['MAX VALUE'] >= product_value)][col].values[0]
```

Output:

```
3%
```

**Note:** given the small size of your table, you could make your life much easier by having a separate column for each number of payments value. Then you could simply do:

```
df[(df['MIN VALUE'] <= product_value) & (df['MAX VALUE'] >= product_value)][no_payments].values[0]
```